# Между двоеточием и псевдоклассом ошибка an identifier expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Цель при наведение на кнопку изменить цвет. Но пишет ошибку.

```
<button  type="button" id="buttonAddNewBlog">+</button>



#buttonAddNewBlog: (тут ошибка) hover {
background-color: green;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример, если убрать `(тут ошибка)` и пробелы, то все работает.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, наверняка в пробеле между двоеточием и псевдоклассом и есть проблема

Comment: Добавил скрин..

Answer (score 3):

```css
#buttonAddNewBlog:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='buttonAddNewBlog'>
```

Вопрос вызван опечаткой, вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: Ошибка банальна, пробел там лишний,вопрос закрыт.